# i have a hot tub installed on a gfci receptacle but when I plug something in that receptacle it doesn't work?

Tags: receptacle

My hot tub is connected to a gfci receptacle but when I plug something in that receptacle it doesn't work?   Is this normal?

Comment: The thing that you plug in doesn't work, or the hot tub doesn't work? What type of hot tub is it?  What does the receptacle look like? What are you plugging in?

Comment: Is the GFU wired to the 'down stream' terminals ?

Comment: The hot tub works.  It's the receptacle that doesn't work.